# How to pass field names to a method and check if they are blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to pass an object (product), and an array of field names to a method, and see of that product has data for all of the fields.

As a helper method I'm looking to do something like:

```
def show_card?(product, fields)
  # Check if any of the fields are blank. In this case:
  fields.each do |f|
    # product.name, product.details, product.color
    # Return false if all are blank.
    # Essentially how do I do: product.f.blank? (product.name.blank? in the first iteration)
  end
end
```

And then in the partial

```
<% if show_card?(@product, ["name", "details", "color"]) %>
  # HTML 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby convention is to use `snake_case` for methods, variables and use `CamelCase` for modules and classes.

```
def show_card?(product, fields)
  # Check if any of the fields are blank. In this case:
  fields.any?{|f| product.send(f.to_sym).empty?}
end
```

Also better to send array of symbols since they will be method calls

```
<% if show_card?(@product, %i[name details color]) %>
  # HTML 
<% end %>
```

and then you don't need `f.to_sym` in the previous method just `send(f)`

Comment: When passing `send` a method which is identified by a string, the string is automatically converted to a symbol. Moreover you should be using `public_send`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `product.send(f).blank?`. You needed to learn the `.send()` method.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
product.attributes.slice(*fields).compact.length == fields.length
```

I guess you could also do:

```
(fields - product.attributes.slice(*fields).compact.keys).empty?
```

To break it down, let's say `product.attributes` returns:

```
{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Foo", "details"=>"Some Details", "color"=>nil, "created_at"=>Fri, 04 Aug 2017 22:42:43 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Fri, 04 Aug 2017 22:42:43 UTC +00:00}
```

And let's say `fields` is:

```
["name", "details", "color"]
```

Then, `product.attributes.slice(*fields)` will return:

```
{"name"=>"Foo", "details"=>"Some Details", "color"=>nil}
```

Adding `compact` will return:

```
{"name"=>"Foo", "details"=>"Some Details"}
```

From there, you can do either of the above approaches and just skip all that iteration business.

BTW, if `fields` includes entries that do not exist on `product`, that's OK. Let's say, `fields` is:

```
["name", "details", "color", "foo_bar"]
```

Then, `product.attributes.slice(*fields).compact` will still return:

```
{"name"=>"Foo", "details"=>"Some Details"}
```

And either of the above approaches will still return `false`.

Comment: this won't make sure it matches the fields, and `product` object will have other fields like id, timestamps ... etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "won't make sure it matches the fields". Could you please say more? And, yes, object will have other fields - but that's immaterial to this approach as they will be discarded by `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be

```
def show_card?(product, fields)
  fields.all? {|field| product&.field }
end
```

[this](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) could be helpful if you don't know about the safe navigation operator `&.`